# My implementation of the Signal protocol for end-to-end encryption in NodeJS and Angular

Tags: typescript, angular-2+, websocket, encryption

I have developed a web app which lets you transfer files from A device to B device, similar to airdrop's concept, working through the server and not peer-to-peer.

I didn't go with a P2P solution because it requires a lot of time to make it work perfectly, and fallbacks in case it doesn't so I didn't really want to go in there, at least not now.

After looking at [this tutorial](https://www.qed42.com/insights/coe/javascript/developing-real-time-secure-chat-application-whatsapp-signal-end-end) to see how to really use the Signal protocol for E2E in JavaScript, I successfully achieved it.

However, I have a feeling that I implemented the handshake incorrectly and insecure.

My main goal was making the server not know by any chance what is the data that is being transferred, which is why I used the [Double Ratchet algorithm by Signal](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/doubleratchet/)

There is my E2E service, which uses the signal algorithm wrapper, as shown in the tutorial above<sup>[1](https://www.qed42.com/insights/coe/javascript/developing-real-time-secure-chat-application-whatsapp-signal-end-end)</sup>, this is my front-end part:

```
@Injectable()
export class E2eeService {

  private signalProtocolManagerUser: any;
  private store: SignalServerStore;

  public initializeNewSession(currentUserId: string) {
    return new Promise<void>(resolve => {
      const store = new SignalServerStore();
      createSignalProtocolManager(currentUserId, undefined, store).then(signalProtocolManagerUser  => {
        this.signalProtocolManagerUser = signalProtocolManagerUser;
        this.store = store;
        resolve();
      });
    })
  }

  public getPreKeyBundle(clientId: string) {
      return this.store.getPreKeyBundle(clientId);
  }

  public encryptMessage(targetClientId: string, message: Blob) {
    const encryptedMessage = this.signalProtocolManagerUser.encryptMessageAsync(targetClientId, message);
    // todo send message to server
  }

  public decryptMessage(senderClientId: string, message: any) {
    return new Promise<Blob>(resolve => {
      this.signalProtocolManagerUser.decryptMessageAsync(senderClientId, message).then(message => {
// TODO convert to blob, save in indexdb
      });
    });
  }
}
```

`signalProtocolManagerUser` is a wrapper for signal lib, as shown in the tutorial, [same as this class](https://github.com/VertikaJain/react-chat-app/blob/master/src/signal/SignalGateway.js), maybe some names changed.

Now this is all working and fine, but here is how my key exchange works:

1. Client A initializes a prekeys bundle
2. Client B initializes a prekeys bundle
3. A sends B their bundle through the server through websocket, and the server passes it to client B through websocket as well without saving the bundle in the server.
4. B sends A their bundle through the server through websocket, and the server passes it to client A through websocket as well without saving the bundle in the server.
5. A sends an encrypted message to B, and B decrypts it.
6. B sends an encrypted message to A, and A decrypts it.
7. Now the connection is secure, since both of the sides have up-to-date synced ratchet.

I would love to get a review to this flow, and if there is a way to improve it or if there is an issue with this approach.

Comment: could you please explain more in detail why do you think there may be a problem with the handshake? I don't know js nor angular, but your description of key exchange seems like a typical exchange in any public-key based algorithm: assuming that `prekeys bundle` contains only public key, not private, server has no way to decrypt the content being passed.

Comment: @morgwai Think of a situation that tomorrow the server gets hacked, or I get some crazy idea and would like to see people's data. What prevents me from deploying a version of the server which also generates a prekeys bundle server-sided for itself, and passes it to the clients, and the clients will think that it's the other's side prekeys bundle, Who promises that you as a client will always get the right key bundle, server can trick both clients by syncing up the ratchet with them and passing the messages as a middle man.

Comment: Are you claiming that the code above achieves what is described in steps 1-7 for the key exchange?

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Nope, the code for the actual exchange wasn't posted, I don't see a reason because the flow is exactly as it is

Comment: The reason I am asking this is that it sounds ridiculous that creating a secure communication channel between A and B through C without C knowing what's going on is possible. My intuition says that it's not possible, unless A and B meet in person and exchanged keys  **directly**.

Comment: ok, now I get what you meant: yes, man in the middle is definitely possible in such scenario, but it's not related to your code: it's a property of public key protocols. There's no way to avoid it without verifying the public keys using other means (such as peers sending fingerprints to each other via a different channel or trusting some certificate authority)

Comment: ...and apologies for my first comment being a bit misleading in this regard maybe: if public keys are not verified, server can replace them during initial exchange exactly the way you describe and read everything. So my first comment should be `s/assuming that prekeys bundle contains only public key/assuming that prekeys bundle contains only _verified_ public key/`

Comment: ...so if you don't plan to use certificates with trusted certificate authority, then basically all you can do is to make it as clear as possible for users that they should verify their keys using another channel before transferring any sensitive data. For example displaying a popup with a message before starting a transfer. As a general note, IMO most communicators, Signal including, don't do enough to make average users aware of man in the middle threat and importance of key verifying...

Comment: I see multiple problems with your question. 1) The code isn't finished and I sincerely doubt this code accomplishes what you want it to accomplish. 2) It also seems like you've left out essential parts of the code before we can do a review. If you wanted a general review of the approach instead of the code itself, you may be in the wrong place altogether. We don't do that without seeing the code, but others might.